# Lista de figuras/tabelas no modelo abntex2

Tags: latex, abntex2

Olá, estou usando o modelo abntex2 para teses. Coloquei as figuras e as tabelas indexadas pelo capítulo. Porém, agora gostaria que nas listas houvesse um espaço entre as figuras/tabelas de um mesmo capítulo. As listas são criadas de modo automático, com o comando `\listoffigures` ou `\listoftables`. Desejo o seguinte formato:

```
 Figura 1.1..............
 Figura 1.2..............
 Figura 1.3..............

 Figura 2.1..............
 Figura 2.2..............
 Figura 2.3..............
```

Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Comment: \lineskip = 18pt.....

Comment: Lara, aparentemente você criou duas contas de usuário, uma delas que você usou para perguntar e outra para responder. Se você quiser, os moderadores podem unificá-las em uma conta só.

Answer (score 4):

Para separar as figuras/tabelas de acordo com os capítulos, bastar colocar no preâmbulo os seguintes comandos:

```
\usepackage{pgffor}
\renewcommand*{\insertchapterspace}{%
              \addtocontents{lof}{\protect\addvspace{10pt}}%
              \addtocontents{lot}{\protect\addvspace{10pt}} }
```

Comment: Lara, aparentemente você criou duas contas de usuário, uma delas que você usou para perguntar e outra para responder. Se você quiser, os moderadores podem unificá-las em uma conta só.